# Insert Testcase in testset and update them with a run

Tags: java, rest, api, alm

I have a custom made reporting which contains testresults of the automated testing. Now, I want to be able to transfer the data of some testcases towards HP ALM but they need to be in a specific testset.

I don't find a way to specify where and how I need to do this with the REST API of HP ALM.

I am already able to login/logout and query HP ALM. But I don't find how to insert data with the restcall.

Below is my function to do the POST call to login/logout

```
try{
        responseText = "";
        requestp = new HttpPost(URL);
        for(int i = 0; i<headerValues.size();i++){
            requestp.setHeader(headerNames.get(i), headerValues.get(i));
        }

        StringEntity input = new StringEntity(XML);
        input.setContentType("text/xml");
        requestp.setEntity(input);

        response = client.execute(requestp);
        rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        String line = "";

        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            responseText += line;
        }
        return responseText;
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: To know the list of endpoints, enter the following in your favorite browser <<ALM_SERVER>>/qcbin/rest/resource-list

Answer (score 0):

To post the results to ALM , You need 4 things
in ALM Test lab section You need to create

1. Create Test set folder
2. Create Test set
3. Create Test instance
4. and finally Create and update Test Run --> This is where you post the results
   The way it works as

`Test_set_folder 
       |_ Test set
             |_ Test instance 1 ( They are test cases in ALM test plan)
             |_ Test instance 2
             |_ Test instance 3`

Then based on Test instances you would create Test runs and here you would insert results

**To create test set folder**

you need `post` to  `http://qcurl/rest/test-set-folder` This will create test-set-folder with and id ( response should have id) 
Now keep that id

**creating test sets**

create test-set using same method as `test-set-folder` when you are posting your payload should have a field `parent-id= test-set-folder-id` returned in previous call. This returns the id of test-set

**creating test set instances**

`http://qcurl/test-instances`

Using the same strategy you could create test-set-instances make sure payload has  `cycle-id=<test-set-id>` returned in previous call

**creating test run**

`http://qcurl/runs`

post the data with `cycle-id=test-set-id` and `testcycl-id=test-instance-id`. This ensures that run is associated with the previous test sets. you can set the `status` value as `not completed`
This returns the run id for that test instance

***Posting (PUT) result back to ALM***

After you have done this now you need to update the results with your results

make sure you now send `put` request to same run

`http://qcurl/run/<id>`

with `status=passed` or `failed`

Hope this helps

Comment: Great, Thank you for your response. Do you have any example on what needs to be in the calls to insert a test instance? Which layout needs to be handled (xml/json)?

Comment: Json Body: `{"Fields":[{"Name":"test-id","values":[{"value":"370"}]},{"Name":"cycle-id","values":[{"value":"6"}]},{"Name":"subtype-id","values":[{"value":"hp.qc.test-instance.EXTERNAL"}]}]}`
Test-id of existing test
 This is the  id of the test-set created previously to which existing tests needs to be attached. Set this as cycle-id

Comment: just to be clear `cycle-id`  value is id of the `test set` where this test instance is going to be. and don't forget the `subtype-id`